# Sub-query issue on ContenDocument and ContentVersion

Tags: soql, contentversion, contentdocument

I have a list of `ContentDocument` IDs which are all tagged to the same Sobject, when a `ContentDocumentId` is selected, I want to retrieve only its latest `ContentVersion` data based on the `LatestPublishedVersionId`, so here is what I tried via vscode.

**Query 1**

```sql
SELECT Id, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = '069XX000000v2OxQAI'
```

**Output**

```
Starting SFDX: Execute SOQL Query...

ID                  LATESTPUBLISHEDVERSIONID
──────────────────  ────────────────────────
069XX000000v2OxQAI  068XX000000v9tCQAQ
Total number of records retrieved: 1.
```

With the LatestPublishedVersionId, I run a query on ContentVersion object and there was one result as expected.

**Query 2**

```sql
SELECT Id, FileType FROM COntentVersion WHERE Id = '068XX000000v9tCQAQ'
```

**Output**

```
Starting SFDX: Execute SOQL Query...
ID                  FILETYPE
──────────────────  ────────
068XX000000v9tCQAQ  TEXT
Total number of records retrieved: 1.
```

But then, when I tried to combined the two queries, there was no result.

**Query 3**

```sql
SELECT Id, FileType FROM COntentVersion WHERE Id IN (SELECT LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = '069XX000000v2OxQAI')
```

**Output**

```
Starting SFDX: Execute SOQL Query...

Total number of records retrieved: 0.
```

Fyi, this was not happening to all files which were tagged to my record, only two records were affected which were uploaded by someone else.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm), it says:

> Note: Depending on how files are shared, queries on ContentDocument and ContentVersion without specifying an ID won't return all files a user has access to. For example, if a user only has access to a file because they have access to a record that the file is shared with, the file won't be returned in a query such as "SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument."

If my individual queries against both ContentDocument and ContentVersion objects each returned a record, why not the combined query?

What did I miss?
Thanks!

**UDPATE**
I assigned myself the "Query All Files" [permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000353032&type=1) via permission set. And now my combined query returns a record.

Specifying list of ID using a subquery does not work. It has to be in form of static string, eg:

```sql
SELECT Id, FileType FROM COntentVersion WHERE Id IN ('068XX000000v9tCQAQ','068XX000000v9tXXXX',...)
```

Comment: Can't you do this based on the "parent object" something like `[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, ContentDocument.CreatedDate, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.FileType, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM Your_SObject__c WHERE Id IN :ids]`?

Comment: @PhilW, my use case is when a file is selected via dropdown box (value is ContentDocumentId), I need to display the latest version of the content using an EMBED tag. So I thought I could just query it directly based on the Content Document ID.